# How to use a single css for multiple Shiny applications

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a set of shiny applications stored in a folder 'apps'. Within the folder app we thus have 'app1', 'app2', etc. In each of those applications we have the default shiny files/folders, i.e. ui.R, server.R, global.R and the folder www.

Each www has its own stylesheet which is loaded into the application in the head tag of ui.R file:

```
tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "template.css")
```

However, there is some template css that should be applied to all the applications. *Were can I best store this template css and use it in all the applications?*

I currently have a copy of the template css in each of the www folders, which works, but it is obviously not ideal when making changes to this css.

Comment: This could be of interest for you: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/addResourcePath.html. "Primarily intended [...] to make supporting JavaScript/CSS files available [...]". Is that going in the right direction for you?

Comment: You can put your CSS in a higher directory or any place and call it directly using `includeCSS("C:/..../styles.css")` or `tags$link(rel='stylesheet', type='text/css', href='C:/.../.../styles.css')`